# Can an external JAR file be created/ran by using the minecraft "versions" folder?

Tags: java, minecraft

I have seen a free Minecraft "hacked" client being passed around called Jello Client. The way you use it is first go to sigmaclient.info, download the folder that is a version, and then put it into the "versions" folder in Minecraft.

The thing is, when you launch the version from the Minecraft launcher, it starts a new loading screen, and on it is the Jello updater.

If you look into your minecraft folder after this runs, you will see a Jello folder (this is normal, lots of mods make their own folders), Sigma5 folder (because this was a collab between Sigma and Jello), and a Jello Bootstrap.jar file.

This jar file worries me, because .jar files can run malicious code, right? Please correct me if I'm wrong, I don't know much about coding.

The thing is, right after I closed Minecraft, my frames for my **whole PC** severely dropped. It slowed down.

After this, I tried deleting the Sigma5, Jello, and the .jar files, and no such luck. They were still there, because it says that they are still running, even though Minecraft was stopped in the Task Manager.

I restarted my PC and it seems like I could delete them, and everything was up to speed, my PC was not slowed down.

How is this possible? How is it possible that launching a version from the Minecraft launcher can create a .jar file and run it, too, probably mining bitcoin?

Answer (score 0):

All that needs to be done is start something that will keep a standalone process/service in the background for that to happen.

Many programs create background processes, but the fact it slowed your pc down to a halt is concerning. It could be bitcoin mining, or even trying to run ransomware as those are pretty CPU intensive, depending on how it's written. I had a friend who's PC froze when something attempted to run ransomware.. which actually saved him, since he was able to shutdown the pc before any damage was done.

Nevertheless, I have never heard of sigma bitcoin mining or running ransomware on other PCs so idk...

I would recommend creating a backup of your important files ASAP, and if possible, reset your pc to factory defaults to be on the safe side... (btw, I am not responsible if you accidentally forgot to back something up and deleted files permanently)

Answer (score -1):

A `.jar` file is a file made with Java and Minecraft is made with Java. So, I think it is safe. Also Jello client takes up 8 Gigs of RAM, according to what I found online.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Java is a programming language. It's not because a safe website uses javascript that all websites are safe. The same principle applies here. It all depends what was written with the language.